# How do I get the type signature to agree with the scala compiler when extracting a value out of an Option[A]?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Let's say I have a variable `x` that is of type `Option[Double]`. I want to get that double out of the variable, so I would suspect that `x.getOrElse(None)` would be the solution.

The type signature of `getOrElse` is as follows:

`def getOrElse[B >: A](default: => B): B`

`None` is simply an `Option[Nothing]`. If I write the following:

```
def mean(xs: Seq[Double]): Option[Double] =
   if (xs.isEmpty) None
   else Some(xs.sum / xs.length)

val avg = mean(xs) getOrElse(None) // compiles
val theAvg: Double = mean(xs) getOrElse(None) // doesn't compile
```

What is going on here with the types? The REPL tells me(using :t) that `avg` is of type `Any`. How can this be? Why does the type match in the first place when `None` is of type `Option[Nothing]`?

What am I not understanding about the types here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the type signature says, `getOrElse` returns a `B` which is a super type of `A` *(which is the type inside the **Option**)*.
That makes sense since, if you have a **Some(a: A)**, then you return that **a**, which is of type `A`, which given it is a subtype of `B`, it can be upcasted to `B` without any problem. And, if it is a **None**, then you return the **default** which is of type `B`.

In your case, you are using **None** for your default, as such the compiler has to figure out what is the [***least weak upper bound***](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/03-types.html#weak-conformance) between `Double` & `Option[Nothing]`, which, as you can see, it is `Any` *(because `Any` is the supertype of every type, and there is not other relation between `Double` & `Option` in the type hierarchy)*.

Now, I believe you are misunderstanding how `getOrElse` works, and what is the purpose of `None`.
I think this is what you really want.

```
// Or any other double that makes sense as a default for you.
val avg: double = mean(xs).getOrElse(default = 0.0d)
```

Comment: That's why mean.fold(0.0d)(identity) is safer. Because the signature doesn't let you specify a different type. Signature of `getOrElse[B >: A](default: => B): B` on the otherhand is `fold[B](default:B)(f: A=>B)`.

Answer (score 1):

> How can this be?

The inferred type `Any` here is a result of the compiler trying to find a common ancestor of `Double` and `Option[Nothing]`. The first common ancestor for both these types is `Any`, and that is why the compiler is inferring that.

> Why does the type match in the first place when `None` is of type
>   `Option[Nothing]`

Great question. Let's inspect the signature for `getOrElse`:

```
final def getOrElse[B >: A](default: => B): B
```

Let's zoom in on the constraint `B >: A`, what does that mean? It means that we can specify any type `B` that is a *supertype* of `A`. Why do we want it to be a super type of `A` to begin with? Why not `A` itself? If the type parameter forced us to use `A` here, we'd be constrained to `Double` and your example wouldn't compile. To answer that question, we need to look at the definition of `Option[A]`:

```
sealed abstract class Option[+A]
```

We see that `A` has a `+` next to it. That plus indicates the presence of covariance. In short, covariance allows us to preserve the "is subtype relation" between types which are themselves defined inside other "container" types, making the following relation hold:

```
A <: B <=> Option[A] <: Option[B]
```

Which means if `A` is a subtype of `B`, we can treat `Option[A]` as a subtype of `Option[B]`. Why does this matter and what does this have to do with the method signature of `getOrElse`? Well, covariance imposes restrictions on type parameters! Covariant type parameters cannot be used as input parameters, or in input parameter position (a position is contravariant if it occurs under an odd number of contravariant type constructors, but the explanation for that is too lengthy so I'll abbreviate), they can only be placed as output parameters in the underlying type containing the type parameter. Thus, the following definition is illegal due to variance laws:

```
final def getOrElse(default: => A): A
```

Because `A` appears here both in the input type and the output type.

Answer (score 1):

Luis did a good job explaining why you got an `Any` for your result type. I just wanted to add that if you wanted to use the `Double` for further processing, but still correctly handle a `None`, you would typically do that with a `map`, to be able to stay inside the `Option` until you actually have a useful value to replace `None` with, like:

```
val message: Option[String] = avg map {x => s"The average is $x."}
println(message getOrElse "Can't take average of empty sequence.")
```